# How to send the same files to multiple devices using wifi

Tags: file, raspberry-pi, wifi, transmission

i have a webserver application using PHP, this application have to send 200MB of data to every device connected to the local network using wifi (Devices are a minimum of 100 to 300). I can send it using a ZIP file (200MB) or sending every single file (from 1 to 10 MB for each file).
Actually i have used TCP protocol on a very good hardware and all works very good! but now, i have to send it using a raspberry Pi 2..

what is the best protocol to do it? I can use a multicast approach? someone know the best way for do it on a raspBerry? I need this operation takes a very short time ;)

ps: For wifi network i have a very good antenna and i can link my raspeberry to the router using cable.

Comment: I tried some real time Java codes on the RPi, so, if you can have it deployed on that, there should be no problem....

Comment: On server side i can use uftp.. there is a way to use it on iOS for receive data?